# How to breed a garnet dragon in Dragonvale?

Tags: dragonvale

How can I breed a garnet dragon in Dragonvale? I already have the island for it, but I can't figure out the breeding combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Garnet dragon can be bred from a Smoke Dragon and Obsidian Dragon, in either order, at the breeding cave or the epic breeding island ([source](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Garnet_Dragon)).